# Constructing Recurrence Relation from Rabbit Problem

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations

Suppose there are two rabbits, initially the number of rabbits double each month
by natural reproduction and some rabbits are either added or removed each month.
Construct a recurrence relation for the number of rabbits at the start of n th month
given that during each month extra 10 rabbits are put on the island.

How to construct this? is it true that i'm thinking of $$\ a_{n} = 2*a_{n-1} + 10 $$
but i don't think that' the right way to write recurence relation

Comment: Why don't you think that it's the right way? It looks completely fine to me.

Comment: I believe that's correct

Comment: @MattiP. i thought we can't use constant in any recurrence relations

Comment: @Ceciliads: A recurrence relation can include constant terms.